# Unable to fire button click event in programmatically created Gridview.FootRow

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, footer, buttonclick

```
Private Sub CreateFooterInputs()

    FooterInputs.Add(New TextBox With {.ID = "Insert1"})

    FooterInputs.Add(New TextBox With {.ID = "Insert2"})

    Dim Insert3 As New DropDownList With {.ID = "Insert3"}
    Insert3.Items.Add("A")
    Insert3.Items.Add("B")
    Insert3.Items.Add("C")
    FooterInputs.Add(Insert3)

End Sub

Private Sub CreateFooterBtns()

    Dim Btn1 As New Button With {.Text = "Button1", .CssClass = "btn btn-info"}
    AddHandler Btn1.Click, AddressOf Btn1_Click
    FooterBtns.Add(Btn1)

    FooterBtns.Add(New Button With {.CommandName = "Insert", .Text = "Add", .CssClass = "btn btn-success"})

    Dim ResetBtn As New HtmlButton With {.InnerText = "Reset"}
    ResetBtn.Attributes("type") = "reset"
    ResetBtn.Attributes("class") = "btn btn-danger"
    FooterBtns.Add(ResetBtn)

End Sub

Protected Sub CreateFooterRow()

    For i = 0 To 2
        With GridView1.FooterRow
            .Cells(i).Controls.Add(FooterInputs(i))
            .Cells(i + 3).Controls.Add(FooterBtns(i))
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Most of the solutions would talk about the page life cycle and the controls should be created earlier, but the below exception occurs at the line `With GridView1.FooterRow`, unless `CreateFooterRow()` is in `Page_PreRender` (probably because the `GridView` hasn't been constructed with rows yet until PreRender stage).

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.'

Then when `CreateFooterRow()` is called in `Page_PreRender`, even if `CreateFooterInputs()` and `CreateFooterBtns()` is in `Page_Init`, the button `Btn1` is unable to fire click event...

Comment: You don't need to be in `Page_PreRender`, `Page_Load` works fine. You just need to execute those methods on every page load and postback.

Comment: The exception is still thrown. No row has been rendered in the stage of `Page_Load`, even after data bound